# How to estimate less conservative standard errors when using post-stratified weights without full information in the survey package?

Tags: r, survey, weighted

I'm encountering (very) huge standard errors in my analysis of proportions with post-stratified data when using the `survey` package.

I'm working with a data set including (normalized) weights calculated via raking by another party. I don't know exactly how the strata have been defined (e.g. "ageXgender" has been used, but it's unclear which categorization has been used). Let's assume a simple random sample with a considerable amount of non-response.

Is there any way to estimate reduced standard errors due to post-stratification without the exact information about the procedure in `survey`? I could recallibrate the weights with `rake()` if I can exactly define the strata but I don't have enough information for this.

I have tried to infer the strata by grouping all equal weights together and thought that I would at least get an upper bound of the reduction in standard errors this way but using them did only lead to marginally reduced standard errors and sometimes even increased standard errors:

```
# An example with the api datasets, pretending that pw are post-stratification weights of unknown origin

library(survey)
data(api)
apistrat$pw <-apistrat$pw/mean(apistrat$pw) #normalized weights
# Include some more extreme weights to simulate my data
mins <- which(apistrat$pw == min(apistrat$pw))
maxs <- which(apistrat$pw == max(apistrat$pw))
apistrat[mins[1:5], "pw"] <- 0.1
apistrat[maxs[1:5], "pw"] <- 10
apistrat[mins[6:10], "pw"] <- 0.2
apistrat[maxs[6:10], "pw"] <- 5
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~1, weights=~pw, data=apistrat)
# "Estimate" stratas from the weights
apistrat$ps_est <- as.factor(apistrat$pw)

dclus_ps_est <-svydesign(id=~1, strata=~ps_est, weights=~pw, data=apistrat)
svymean(~api00, dclus1)
svymean(~api00, dclus_ps_est)
#this actually increases the se instead of reducing it
```

My real weights are also much more complex with 700 unique values in 1000 cases.

Is it possible to somehow approximate the reduction of standard errors due to post-stratification without knowing the real variables and categories and -especially- population values for `rake`? Could I use `rake` with some assumptions about the variables and categories used in the strata definitions but without the population totals in some way?

Answer (score 0):

If your data are already raked, then you know the population totals exactly: raking makes the estimated population totals equal the true population totals for the raking variables.  So, if you know the raking variables you can estimate the population totals then rake.  The raking won't change the weights (because *ex hypothesi* these were already raked) but it will change the standard error estimates

(The next version of the `survey` package will have an option in `svydesign` to do exactly this.)